# Adjacency matrix from pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, networkx, adjacency-matrix

The below is a small example of what I am trying to do in python.
I am working with networks, having 15000 distinct nodes in my network.
Data is from pandas dataset:

```
Node Target  Node_Attrib
mom    dad       0.2
mom    grandmother 0.12
mom    grandfather 0.24
mom    Lucy      0.2
dad    mom       0.4
dad    Lucy      0.3
Lucy   mom       0.1
Lucy   dad       0.3
Lucy   Mark      0.1
Lucy   grandmother 0.2
Lucy   grandfather 0.1
```

The network is created as follows:

```
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,’Node’, ‘Target’,[‘Node_Attrib’]
```

Where nx is networkx.
Since I would like to perform some analysis, I would need to use adjacency matrix.
I am thinking of using crosstab for doing that:

```
adj = pd.crosstab(df.Node, df.Target)
idx=adj.columns.union(df.index)
adj=adj.reindex(index=idx,columns=idx,fill_value=0)
```

I am wondering if this is the best approach to get the adjacency matrix in python, also due to the number of nodes in the network.
Do you know a different approach that could better manage with thousands of nodes (and edges) in Python?

Comment: What would be the expected output for the given input?

Comment: I would expect an adjacency matrix for the data in the example in order to be extended to my whole dataset (10000 nodes approx). I used this approach but I am not sure it is ok

Comment: How is networkx related to the question? What kind of analysis you are doing that cannot be done in the current graph representation?

Comment: I need networkx for a graphical representation of my network. My question is how Incan create an adjacency matrix in python from a pandas dataframe. If networkx is not an appropriate tag (though my question is related to networks and graphs in python), please feel free to remove it

Comment: Can you clarify if your graph is directed? `(mom, Lucy)` has a different value to `(Lucy, mom)` in your table. Also, do you want the value of the matrix to be populated with the related `"Node_Attrib"` value of the edge?

Comment: Hi Reti43, my graph is directed so they should have different value (Node_Attrib). It would be awesome if the value of the matrix could be populated with/without the related node attribute, just for seeing the differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, [`nx.from_pandas_edgelist()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html) will create an undirected graph by default. That means it first sets the value of the edge `(mom, Lucy)` to 0.2, as it's the first time this edge is encountered in your table. But when you parse `(Lucy, mom)`, the same edge will be updated to the new value.

```
>>> G.get_edge_data('mom', 'Lucy')
{'Node_Attrib': 0.1}
```

For a directed graph, change the line to

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Node', 'Target', ['Node_Attrib'], create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

Networkx has the function [`nx.adjacency_matrix()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.linalg.graphmatrix.adjacency_matrix.html) which creates a scipy sparse matrix. This is useful to save memory when not all edges have values.

```
>>> adj = nx.adjacency_matrix(G, weight='Node_Attrib')
>>> adj[0,1]    # (mom, dad) edge as the node ordering is taken from `G.nodes`
0.2
>>> array = adj.todense()   # if for some reason you need the whole matrix
```

---

As the documentation of that function states, you can also create a pure Python equivalent of a sparse matrix with a dict-of-dicts. But if you want to perform some analysis, I suspect the array option from above will be more suitable for you.

```
>>> adj = nx.convert.to_dict_of_dicts(G)
>>> adj['mom']['Lucy']['Node_Attrib']
0.2
```

This would require a bit of a clean-up so that `adj[node1][node2]` gives you the edge value straight up. You'd also need to actually use it with `adj.get(node1, {}).get(node2, 0.)` to not run into any `KeyError`.